# C++ reading date into struct

Tags: c++, date

I am a risk modeler who frequently use SAS and SQL but new to C++. I am currenting studying IOS issues and have a question about date may need you guys' help. suppose in a txt file there is a field called Origination_date with format: mm/dd/yy. My purpose is to read it into such a 
variable:

```
struct orig_date
{
    int oyr;//extract year from origination date
    int omonth;
    int oqtr;//no necessary at begin
    int oday;
};
```

what I should do to get what I want? thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any choice at all, don't invent your own type for this task.

C and C++ already provide `tm` struct that contains a broken-down date and time, along with routines to convert to/from `time_t`, and do I/O. Unless I had an overwhelming reason to do otherwise, I'd just use that. For example, to read a date in the format you've given, you could use something like this:

```
std::tm orig;

std::cin >> std::get_time("%m/%d/%y", &orig);
```

The fields you've given will then be available as `orig.tm_year`, `orig.tm_mon`, and `orig.tm_mday`.

Comment: Thank you Jerry, that's what I want! let me ask one more question, here you used cin, I guess it should be used to get input from user? What if I want import a column called orig_date from a TXT file and put the values into orig? Thanks.

Comment: @VictorYan: Pretty similar--just open an `ifstream`, and use it instead of `cin`: `std::ifstream in("somefile.txt"); in >> std::get_time("%m/%d/%y", &orig);` Of course, if there's anything else in the file, you'll have to deal with that appropriately as well...